# Why is edges plural in the relay specification?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graph, graphql, relayjs

Here is an example of a graphql query.

A person has multiple hats,

```
person{
    hats{
        color
    }
}
```

Using the relay specification, https://relay.dev/graphql/connections.htm, this query becomes

```
person{
    hats{
        edges{
             node { color }
             cursor
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

The idea to have in mind is the person has many hats, and you can draw a tree (this is not quite right, see below)

```
         (person)
              |||
  |---------------|------------|
  |               |            |
(hat1)         (hat 2)      (hat 3)
```

The lines going from person to a hat is an `edge`.

I have 2 questions about this:

1. Why is node inside of edges? This doesn't make graphical sense.
2. Why is the `edges` name plural, instead of being just a singular `edge`? I can't imagine a single use case for this. Please give an example if you know one.

For instance, here is the 'correct' diagram of the relay specification

```
         (person)
   _________|||____________________
  |||-------------|||------------|||
  |||-------------|||------------|||
  |||             |||            |||
 (hat1)         (hat 2)      (hat 3)
```

Note that there are many edges going from a person to a hat. This doesn't make sense to me

Answer (score 0):

```
    A
   /|\
  e f g
 /  |  \
B   C   D
```

Consider this tree with the four nodes A, B, C, and D as well as the edges e, f, and g.

A has connections with B, C, and D.
A and B are connected through the edge e.
A therefore has 3 edges (plural) but from every edge (coming from A) I only get to a single other node (singular).

GraphQL is inspired by thinking about the connection between entities in a data set as graphs. The entities form the nodes, while the relationships between them can be considered edges in the graph. On the edge, we would store information about the relationship of the two entities.

I - personally - would not put too much thought into this whole naming from Relay. It is just one way to do pagination that worked very well for Facebook. Facebook is a company that probably has interviews that tend to favor computer science grads.

Here is my interpretation of the "correct" diagram according to your example:

```
         (person)
   _________|||____________________
  |          |                     |
  |          |                     |
  |          |                     |
 (hat1)      (hat 2)          (hat 3)
```

Comment: I kind of wanted to know why they chose this specification. The lack of explanation anywhere tells me that people dont know what theyre talking about and just kiss up to facebook hand me downs

Comment: @MondoDuke What else should have been chosen? It clearly shows a person has property hats.And that is modelled as multiple edges from Person object to hat object(which is the represented as node here). Herku has rightly explained it.